# How to mutate str_locate_all into single list containing all positions involved in pattern

Tags: r, stringr

I am not able to "deconvolute" str_locate_all output so as to get all indexes involved in the pattern (not just start and end).

Here is the type of str_locate_all() output I get:

```
[1]]
       start end
[1,]     4   7

[[2]]
       start end
[1,]     8  12
[2,]    30  33
```

and how I would like to mutate it:

```
[[1]]
[1]  4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 8 9 10 11 12 30 31 32 33
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the list, and then iterate through each row to create the sequence.

```r
x <- list(matrix(c(4, 7), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))),
          matrix(c(8, 30, 12, 33), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("start", "end"))))
```

Here it is done in base R.

```r
lapply(x,
       function(y) unlist(apply(y, 1,
                                function(z) seq(z[1], z[2]), simplify = FALSE)))
```

Gives the desired result.

```r
[[1]]
[1] 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10 11 12 30 31 32 33
```